# PHP CSS :: inline work but not internal and external stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css

I have created **PHP** files which accept data from $_GET method.

After that I use all the data I get to create HTML pages. Nothing is wrong with the data but in **CSS** I cannot style HTML elements. Except when it comes to inline styling, that works but it is not good to maintain.

I try to use like this but it doesn't work , Please Help

***THANK IN ADVANCE***

Example.php

```
<?php
$dataCover      = $_GET['dataCover'];
$dataTitle      = $_GET['dataTitle'];
$dataTag        = $_GET['dataTag'];
$dataDir        = $_GET['dataDir'];
$dataYear       = $_GET['dataYear'];
$dataCreated    = $_GET['dataCreated'];
$dataModified   = $_GET['dataModified'];
$userAUID       = $_GET['userAUID'];
$galleryID      = $_GET['galleryID'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        #container img{
            height: 230px;
            width: 200px;
        }
        #container .center{
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/se.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <div data-role ="page" id ="page1">
        <div data-role ="header">
            <h1> header </h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="container">
                <img class="center" src="<?echo $dataCover?>" alt=""/>
                <p id="title"><?echo $dataTitle;?></p>
                <p id="tag"><?echo $dataTag;?></p>
                <p id="created">Created : <?echo $dataCreated?></p>
                <p id="modified">modified : <?echo $dataModified?></p>
                <a href="http://54.249.251.55/AUgallery"  target="_blank" data-url="<? echo $dataCreated ?>" rel="external" data-role="button">View Ebook-Gallery</a>
                <a href="<?echo 'http://localhost/webAPP/php/addBookmark.php?userAUID='.$userAUID.'&noteID='.$galleryID?>"data-ajax="false" rel="external" data-role="button">Bookmark</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your php and html are in same file?

Comment: Yes sir!? It's in the same file but the file name is example.php

Comment: It does work for me using external css link.

Comment: Everything looks right, and I even tried copying your code onto a page to test it out, and the embedded css works for me.. can you give us any more information? If you use an inspector, can you see any styles being applied? Are there any other factors at play that we might need to know about?

Comment: I use JQM is that connect to somethings?

Comment: What browser do you use. Since you are using JQM: Are you sure you are testing this on a device that knows how to render the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

When you move your css from inline to style sheet file, you have to refresh your page with Ctrl+F5. Maybe it's coming from the cache. 
Also you can assign your css to the image by jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any reference to any **external stylesheet**, so it seems like you have forgotten to do this.

Put this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Somewhere in the head. Maybe before the script tags.

Make sure you **adjust the path** to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes When you want to apply external css you have to  give the path after the <title> tags within the <head> tags .just follow the html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<!--Here css is the folder name where you have keep the style.css file -->

    <script src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/se.js"></script>
</head>
```